# camshift object tracking problems

Tags: c, opencv

i have developed camshift algorithm by watching some tutorials..but unfortunately it didn't track the selected object....here is my code..i am a beginner to opencv and i need help..problem is the rectangle doesn't follow the object to track...

this my code:

```
bool destroy=false;
 CvRect box;
 CvRect track_window;   
 bool drawing_box = false;
 cv::Mat imageROI;
 IplImage *image = 0, *hsv = 0, *hue = 0, *mask = 0, *backproject = 0, *histimg = 0;   
 CvHistogram *hist = 0;   
 int hdims = 16;   
 float hranges_arr[] = {0,180};   
 float* hranges = hranges_arr;   
 int vmin = 10, vmax = 256, smin = 30;   
 IplImage *image2;
 CvScalar hsv2rgb( float hue );
 CvConnectedComp track_comp;   
 CvBox2D track_box;   

 void draw_box(Mat img, CvRect rect)
 {
   imageROI= img(cv::Rect(box.x,box.y,box.width,box.height));
cv::rectangle(img, cvPoint(box.x, box.y), cvPoint(box.x+box.width,box.y+box.height),
          cvScalar(0,0,255) ,2);

 }

  CvScalar hsv2rgb( float hue )   
{   
   int rgb[3], p, sector;   
    static const int sector_data[][3]=   
    {{0,2,1}, {1,2,0}, {1,0,2}, {2,0,1}, {2,1,0}, {0,1,2}};   
   hue *= 0.033333333333333333333333333333333f;   
    sector = cvFloor(hue);   
   p = cvRound(255*(hue - sector));   
   p ^= sector & 1 ? 255 : 0;   

      rgb[sector_data[sector][0]] = 255;   
     rgb[sector_data[sector][1]] = 0;   
     rgb[sector_data[sector][2]] = p;   

    return cvScalar(rgb[2], rgb[1], rgb[0],0);
}

     void my_mouse_callback( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
      {
       IplImage* frame = (IplImage*) param;

    switch( event )
       {
      case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
     {
      if( drawing_box )
      {
          box.width = x-box.x;
          box.height = y-box.y;
      }
  }
  break;

  case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
  {
      drawing_box = true;
      box = cvRect( x, y, 0, 0 );

  }
  break;

  case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
  {
      drawing_box = false;
      if( box.width < 0 )
      {
          box.x += box.width;
          box.width *= -1;
      }

      if( box.height < 0 )
      {
          box.y += box.height;
          box.height *= -1;
      }

      draw_box(frame, box);

  }
  break;

  case CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP:
  {
      destroy=true;
  }
  break;

  default:
  break;
} }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
     {

VideoCapture cap(0);  
if(!cap.isOpened())   
    return -1;

  Mat image;
   Mat frame;
//cv::Mat image= cv::imread("1.jpg");
 cap>>image;
if (!image.data)
    return 0; 


// Display image
cv::namedWindow("Image");
cv::imshow("Image",image);

IplImage* img = new IplImage(image);
cvSmooth(img,img,CV_GAUSSIAN,3,0,0.0,0.0);
IplImage* temp = cvCloneImage(img);
cvSetMouseCallback("Image", my_mouse_callback, (void*) img);


while( 1 )
{
 if (destroy) 
{
  cvDestroyWindow("Image"); break;
}
cvCopyImage(img, temp);

if (drawing_box) 
    draw_box(temp, box);


cvShowImage("Image", temp);

if (cvWaitKey(15) == 27) 
    break;
}

cvReleaseImage(&temp);
cvDestroyWindow("Image");


    for(;;)
  {
      int i, bin_w, c;   

       cap >> frame;
        IplImage* frame_ipl = new IplImage(frame);
        hsv = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame_ipl), 8, 3 ); 
        image2 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame_ipl), 8, 3 );
        hue = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame_ipl), 8, 1 );   
        mask = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame_ipl), 8, 1 );   
        backproject = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame_ipl), 8, 1 );   
        hist = cvCreateHist( 1, &hdims, CV_HIST_ARRAY, &hranges, 1 );   
        histimg = cvCreateImage( cvSize(320,200), 8, 3 );   
        cvZero( histimg ); 

        cvCopy( frame_ipl, image2, 0 );   
        cvCvtColor( image2, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );   

        int _vmin = vmin, _vmax = vmax;   

        cvInRangeS( hsv, cvScalar(0,smin,MIN(_vmin,_vmax),0),   
                    cvScalar(180,256,MAX(_vmin,_vmax),0), mask );   
        cvSplit( hsv, hue, 0, 0, 0 );   

            float max_val = 0.f;   
            cvSetImageROI( hue, box );   
            cvSetImageROI( mask, box );   
            cvCalcHist( &hue, hist, 0, mask );   
            cvGetMinMaxHistValue( hist, 0, &max_val, 0, 0 );   
            cvConvertScale( hist->bins, hist->bins, max_val ? 255. / max_val : 0., 0 );   
            cvResetImageROI( hue );   
            cvResetImageROI( mask );   
            track_window = box;   


            cvZero( histimg );   
            bin_w = histimg->width / hdims;   
            for( i = 0; i < hdims; i++ )   
            {   
                int val = cvRound( cvGetReal1D(hist->bins,i)*histimg->height/255 );   
                CvScalar color = hsv2rgb(i*180.f/hdims);   
                cvRectangle( histimg, cvPoint(i*bin_w,histimg->height),   
                             cvPoint((i+1)*bin_w,histimg->height - val),   
                             color, -1, 8, 0 );   
            }   

        cvCalcBackProject( &hue, backproject, hist );   
        cvAnd( backproject, mask, backproject, 0 );   
         cvCamShift( backproject, track_window, cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ), &track_comp, &track_box );   
        track_window = track_comp.rect;   
        cv::rectangle(frame, track_window, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
       cv::namedWindow("result");
       cv::imshow("result",frame);


if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you shorten your code a bit just enough so it reproduces the error? Also what else happens to the rectangle, does it move at all? Also, what have you tried to fix it and hasn't worked?

Comment: please do not use the c-api, but the c++ one.

Answer (score 0):

but I use the c-api

What might this code be changed to IplImage :

```
void draw_box(Mat img, CvRect rect)
 {
   imageROI= img(cv::Rect(box.x,box.y,box.width,box.height));
cv::rectangle(img, cvPoint(box.x, box.y), cvPoint(box.x+box.width,box.y+box.height),
          cvScalar(0,0,255) ,2);

 }
```